# Read --> Modify -->Write large .csv files with Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to be as efficient as possible with modifying large .csv files. I have a file which has about 20 million rows and I would like to perform a few changes to it to prepare it for Tableau visualization:

1) Select relevant columns 
2) Rename columns
3) Parse dates
4) Create simple columns (combining two fields into a unique ID and adding an integer column)
5) Export to a consolidated .csv again (so I don't want to have repeat headers other than the initial one and I do not need an index column).

I get a memory error on my poor laptop so I would like to learn how to use chunksize to read the file, process my changes, and then export to a common .csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\MyFile.csv.gz', dtype = 'str', chunksize = 10000, iterator=True, compression = 'gzip', usecols = ['EmployeeID', 'Created Date', 'InteractionID'])
df['Total']=1
df['UniqueID']= df['EmployeeID'] + df['InteractionID']
df['Short Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date'])
df['Short Date'] = df['Short Date'].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%m%d%y'))
df['Roster ID'] = df['EmployeeID'] + df['Short Date'].map(str)
print('Modified successfully.')
```

combine = concat(df, ignore_index=True) #I know something like this needs to be created but I am not sure how

```
combine.to_csv(r'C:\Users\test.csv', index= False, encoding = 'utf-8') #this would create the original file
```

Sample Raw:

InteractionID, Created Date, EmployeeID, Repeat Date

07927,04/01/2014 14:05:10,912a, 04/01/2014 14:50:03,
02158,04/01/2014 13:44:05,172r,04/04/2014 17:47:29, 
44279,04/01/2014 17:28:36,217y,04/07/2014 22:06:19

Comment: Are you struggling just with the writing out portion? you don't need to concat if you are just wanting to write out the modified portion. Essentially you just write out the first chunk as normal and then on each subsequent chunk add the params to `to_csv`: `mode='a', header=None` this will append to the existing csv and not write the headers out again as you already did this the first time.

Comment: I get an error when trying to modify the file (add columns in chunks etc).

TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object does not support item assignment

The way I picture it is that I select like 10,000 rows (chunksize = 10000) and then my computer would add the columns, rename, etc for those 10,000 rows. Then it would move on to the next 10,000. At the end it would combine everything neatly into one .csv

Comment: This is almost certainly quicker and easier to do using a simple line iterator and string proccessing and bypassing pandas altogether.